# increasing integer in mix string include : string + integer

Tags: java

I want automatic increasing integer in string ( is code of products )
ex : ABC00001 -> ABC00002;  ABC00009 -> ABC00010.... and ABC99999 -> ABC000001...
It's just only increase integer. I don't know how to solve it because it has number "0000".
I search a function :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   Pattern digitPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d)"); // EDIT: Increment each digit.

   Matcher matcher = digitPattern.matcher("test001check2");
   StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
   while (matcher.find())
   {
       matcher.appendReplacement(result, String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)) + 1));
   }
   matcher.appendTail(result);
   System.out.println(result.toString());

  }
```

But it crease each digit. How can i solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   // use \d+ to match the whole number
   Pattern digitPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");

   Matcher matcher = digitPattern.matcher("test001check2");
   StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
   while (matcher.find())
   {
      String match = matcher.group(1);
      int numDigits = match.length(); // get number of digits in the string
      int newValue = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)) + 1; // get the raw value of the string, add one
      // pad the new value with the right number of zeros, so 001 will become 002 and not just 2
      String newValueStr = String.format("%0" + numDigits + "d", newValue);
      matcher.appendReplacement(result, newValueStr);
   }
   matcher.appendTail(result);
   System.out.println(result.toString());

  }
```

Output on my machine: `test002check3`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question one possible approach is to take the first 3 characters from the `String` and then extract everything else into an `int`. Then you can format the output (and extract it into a method) with something like,

```
private static String increment(String str) {
    String base = str.substring(0, 3);
    int val = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(4));
    return String.format("%s%06d", base, val + 1);
}
```

And then to test it

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "ABC000001";
    System.out.println(str);
    System.out.println(increment(str));
}
```

Output is

```
ABC000001
ABC000002
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, sorry for my question is not clearly. I just want increase the last integer in mix string.
ex : test001check2 -> test001check3;  test001check9->test001check00;  test001check09 -> test001check10;  test001check99 -> test001check000....
And now i found a function with above requirement.

```
public final char MIN_DIGIT = '0';
public final char MAX_DIGIT = '9';

public String incrementedCode(String original) {
    if(original != null && !"".equals(original.trim())){
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(original);
        int i = buf.length() -1;
        while(i >= 0) {
           char c = buf.charAt(i);
           if(c >= MIN_DIGIT && c<= MAX_DIGIT){
               c++;
               if(c > MAX_DIGIT) { // overflow, carry one
                  if(buf.charAt(i - 1) > MAX_DIGIT){
                      buf.setCharAt(i, MIN_DIGIT);
                      buf.insert(i, "0");
                      return buf.toString();
                  }
                  buf.setCharAt(i, MIN_DIGIT);
                  i--;
                  continue;
               }
               buf.setCharAt(i, c);
               return buf.toString();
           }
           i--;
        }
        // overflow at the first "digit", need to add one more digit
        buf.insert(0, MIN_DIGIT);
        return buf.toString();
    }else{
        return "";
    }
}
```